# Replace char sequence in a string not working

Tags: java

I am retreiving data from a URL into a String a, and passing this string as an argument to gson's fromJson method. Now I need to replace some of the substrings in string a.

```
    String url = "abc";
    String a = getDataFromURL(url); //this string contains all the data from the URL, and getDataFromURL is the method that reads the data from the URL.
    String tmp = "\"reservation\":\"www.\"";
    String tmpWithHttp = "\"reservation\":\"http://www.\"";

    if(a.contains(tmp))
    {
    a = a.replace(a, tmpWithHttp);
    }
```

All the data in the URL is JSON. The requirement I have here is, if the String a contains a substring - `"reservation":"www.`, replace that with `"reservation":"http://www.`

The above code I have is not working. Could someone please help me here?

Comment: In addition to Rohit Jain's answer, your code is checking for `"reservation":"www."`, not `"reservation":"www.` (as your question specifies).  That small difference could cause it to not find the replacement string.

Comment: @Vulcan: Post it as an answer. I am pretty sure this is the real error here.

Comment: @Vulcan - You are 100% right. Yup, post it as an answer, and I will accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your question, you specify that you want to replace `"reservation":"www.`. However, in your code, you've added an extra escaped quote, causing the replacement to search for `"reservation":"www."`, which isn't present in the string.

Simply remove that last escaped quote:

```
String tmp = "\"reservation\":\"www.";
```

Answer (score 3):

You probably mean:

```
a = a.replace(tmp, tmpWithHttp);
```

instead of:

```
a = a.replace(a, tmpWithHttp);
```

And you don't need to do a `contains()` check before replacing. `String#replace` method will replace only if the substring to replace is present. So, you can remove the surrounding `if`.

Comment: Yup, sorry about that. I didn't paste my code as is. Modified it here in the question ;)